# Formatting Dates with "-" separators and not "/"

Tags: excel, vba, date, format

A file is given to me in such a way that the date is included in the file name.

I have written a code to retrieve the file based on the date.

The file name, which cannot be changed, is xxxx_MM-DD-YYYY.

For half of the month my code works. e.g of the file name is xxxx_05-15-2020, the user can enter in the date, 05-15-2020, and it will be retrieved.

If the user puts in 05-03-2020 , Excel changes this format to 05/03/2020, and based on the new format, the code will not work as it is looking for "-" separators and not "/".

How can I choose MM-DD-YYYY formatting?

Comment: What is your local default date format?  dd/mm/yyyy ?

Comment: If you format the input cell as text then Excel will not do anything with whatever the user enters.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work regardless whether your date is stored as a date type variable or string type variable:

```
dateString = Replace(dateVar, "/", "-")
```

If you need to convert the date to a date type variable, you could use `cDate` like this

```
cDate(dateString)
```

Assuming your date is stored as a date type variable, you could format it this way:

```
Format(dateVar, "dd-mm-yyyy")
```

Read more about the `Format` function [here](https://www.excelfunctions.net/vba-format-function.html)

Comment: Thanks for this Miqi, can you advise how to implement this into my existing code as im having trouble:

WorkBooks.open  filename := "C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\BTM\Report " & Format(Range("E3"), "mm.dd.yyyy") & ".xlsx"

Comment: Have you tried `Debug.print "C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\BTM\Report " & Format(Range("E3"), "mm.dd.yyyy") & ".xlsx"` in the immediate window? Unless the file path you're specifying is an exact match to an actual file path it won't work.